# A Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I want to fetch all the employees who are paid 17.5 hourly and there project title is HR System.

```
employee table: employee_id (PK), employee_name
project table: project_code (PK), project_title
project_team: project_code (FK), employee_id (FK), hourly_rate
```

I have tried with the following query with I get syntax error. Where am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT employee.`department_id`, employee.`employee_name`, project_team.`hourly_rate`, project.`project_title`
FROM
(employee INNER JOIN project_team ON employee.`employee_id` = project_team.`employee_id`)
AND
(project INNER JOIN project_team ON project.`project_code` = project_team.`project_code`)
AND
(project_team.`hourly_rate` = 17.50)
AND
(project.`project_title` = "HR System");
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and
(project inner join project_team on project.`project_code` = project_team.`' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this statement

```
SELECT employee.`department_id`, employee.`employee_name`, project_team.`hourly_rate`, project.`project_title`
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN project_team ON employee.`employee_id` = project_team.`employee_id`
inner join project ON project.`project_code` = project_team.`project_code`
where
(project_team.`hourly_rate` = 17.50)
AND
(project.`project_title` = "HR System");
```

You can not use `AND` in a from clause. You have to use the correct `join` syntax.

Comment: @ImamBux:- Also I would suggest that try to create alias name for the tables so that your query becomes more readable in JOINS :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `AND` clause in `FROM` statements.

```
SELECT
    employee.`department_id`,
    employee.`employee_name`,
    project_team.`hourly_rate`,
    project.`project_title`
FROM project_team
INNER JOIN employee
    ON employee.`employee_id` = project_team.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN project
    ON project.`project_code` = project_team.`project_code`
WHERE project_team.`hourly_rate` = 17.50
    AND project.`project_title` = "HR System";
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to put the `AND` near the `JOINS`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  employee.`department_id`,
  employee.`employee_name`,
  project_team.`hourly_rate`,
  project.`project_title`
FROM project_team
INNER JOIN employee
  ON employee.`employee_id` = project_team.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN project
 ON project.`project_code` = project_team.`project_code`
WHERE project_team.`hourly_rate` = 17.50
AND project.`project_title` = "HR System";;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can do the job :

```
SELECT employee.`employee_id`, employee.`employee_name`, project_team.`hourly_rate`, project.`project_title`
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN project_team
ON employee.`employee_id` = project_team.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN project
ON project.`project_code` = project_team.`project_code`
WHERE project_team.`hourly_rate` = 17.50
AND project.`project_title` = "HR System";
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` wher you want to join 2 tables, and don't forget `WHERE` when you want to test values.